# Custom Phong Shader with USE_NORMALMAP

Tags: three.js

I've created a simple Phong based custom shader which creates the opacity from luminosity. Now when I'm trying to add Normal Map functionality WebGL is throwing me errors.

```
var vertexShader = THREE.ShaderLib.phong.vertexShader;
var fragmentShader = getShader();
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(THREE.ShaderLib.phong.uniforms);

var defines = {};
defines[ "USE_MAP" ] = "";
defines[ "USE_NORMALMAP" ] = "";

var color_map = loader.load( 'img/colored.jpg' );
var normal_map = loader.load( 'img/skin_normal.jpg' );

uniforms.map = { type: "t", value: color_map};
uniforms.normalMap = { type: "t", value: normal_map};
uniforms.normalScale = { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2( 0.25, 0.25 )};
```

If if I comment out the USE_NORMALMAP everything works as expected (without normal map obviously) but if it's enabled I'm getting this:

```
three.js:16058 THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.Gt @ three.js:16058Kt @ three.js:16578acquireProgram @ three.js:16996w @ three.js:21057E @ three.js:21214renderBufferDirect @ three.js:20163b @ three.js:20986render @ three.js:20727render @ VREffect.js:396value @ a-scene.js:425(anonymous function) @ bind.js:12
three.js:16612 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:684: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled
ERROR: 0:685: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled
ERROR: 0:686: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled
ERROR: 0:687: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled
```

I'm assuming it's because I'm not loading something in the shader or passing the normalMap and normalScale somehow in wrong format. What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you show more code of the material creation and the getShader() function? It will help us provide a better answer.

Comment: Taken from [HERE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3145) "You are missing "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable" from your shader code. Three.js adds it automatically for MeshPhongMaterial if the material has bumpMap or normalMap properties. I guess it differs between browsers and drivers and whatnot whether it is required."

Comment: ShaderMaterial has an `etensions.derivitives` variable which you can set to true that may help you. eg. `mymaterial.extensions.derivatives = true` but what the consequences are I do not know.

Comment: @2pha Thanks a lot! Using `mymaterial.extensions.derivatives = true` fixed this quick and easy!